# OSX: Command line display of temperature sensor status

Tags: macos, temperature

I was wondering how one checks temperature status (CPU, chassis) from a OSX Terminal? I have a few machines and am trying to incorporate this into a series of diagnostic scripts we maintain.

I didn't see anything immediately obvious in system_profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a built in feature.

Check out [this question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59580/get-disk-temperature-in-terminal) at askdifferent.

Comment: This is true to the best of my knowledge. Looking to license some of those third party libraries